# Nested include with where statements using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, include

the structure of my app is as follows:
c

```
lass Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :team_members
  has_one :legal_contract
  has_many :documents
end

class ProjectsTeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :team_member
end

class LegalContract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class TeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects_team_members
  has_many :projects, through: :projects_team_members
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

I am trying to find all team_members who are associated with legal_contract with one of ids from an array. Trying the includes method:

```
  team_members = TeamMember.includes( {projects_team_members: [ { project: :legal_contract} ] } )
```

I wonder now how do I narrow it down now to pull only those tmembers and not all. I tried

```
arry= [1,3,5]
team_members = TeamMember.includes( {projects_team_members: [ { project: :legal_contract} ] }).where('legal_contract.id IN', arry)
```

but getting an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...s"."updated_at" AS t0_r6, "projects_team_members"."" AS t1_r...
```

Does anyone know? Thanks

****UPDATE****
Thanks to Karlingen

```
TeamMember.joins(:projects => :legal_contract).where(legal_contracts: { id: [1,3,5] })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to accomplish this through a join like so:

```
TeamMember.joins(:projects => :legal_contract).where(legal_contracts: { id: [1,3,5] })
```

First you join the projects table and its legal contract. And then you search for all legal contracts that has the given ids.

Do note that the key in the Where clause is written in plural since it is the name of the table.

Comment: I tried that and got NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: I also tried to modify this: TeamMember.joins(:projects => :legal_contract).where(legal_contract: { id: LegalContract.find(1,3,5) } ) but got ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "legal_contract"

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column team_members.legal_contract does not exist

Comment: @evoo is the table name for LegalContract called legal_contracts? If it is, the posted solution should be working fine. Otherwise you should be changing the key to the proper table name

Comment: Karlingen, yes it is. Everything else work perfectly. I am pulling my hair out at this point  :/ so double checked and select * from legal_contracts return records - tested in pgAdmin.

Comment: @evoo one last try then: TeamMember.joins(:projects => :legal_contract).where(legal_contracts: { id: [1,3,5] })

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a primary key for `projects_team_members`, are you sure you have one?

It appears as though Rails is creating invalid syntax when trying to find a `projects_team_members`:

`"projects_team_members".""`

Comment: Hi Brennan, This is many-to-many association and I have no primary keys on that table, only project_id and team_member_id- works perfectly.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry bout that @evoo